# Is it possible to sort a groups of lines in vim?

Tags: sorting, vim

As far as I know vim's :sort method will sort each line. I have some code that is in groups of 3 lines. How can I sort this? Please ignore the shitty code, it's a legacy app :'(

I would like to sort by the case 'AF' line but ignore (group) the country and break line

```
case 'AF':
  country = 'Afghanistan';
  break;,
case 'AL':
  country = 'Albania';
  break;,
case 'DZ':
  country = 'Algeria';
  break;,
case 'AS':
  country = 'American Samoa';
  break;,
case 'AD':
  country = 'Andorra';
  break;,
case 'AO':
  country = 'Angola';
  break;,
case 'AI':
  country = 'Anguilla';
  break;,
case 'AQ':
  country = 'Antarctica';
  break;,
case 'AG':
  country = 'Antigua And Barbuda';
  break;,
case 'AR':
  country = 'Argentina';
  break;,
case 'AM':
  country = 'Armenia';
  break;,
case 'AW':
  country = 'Aruba';
  break;,
case 'AU':
  country = 'Australia';
  break;,
case 'AT':
  country = 'Austria';
  break;,
case 'AZ':
  country = 'Azerbaijan';
  break;,
case 'BS':
  country = 'Bahamas';
  break;,
case 'BH':
  country = 'Bahrain';
  break;,
case 'BD':
  country = 'Bangladesh';
  break;,
case 'BB':
  country = 'Barbados';
  break;,
case 'BY':
  country = 'Belarus';
  break;
```

Comment: Why not refactor it to `var COUNTRIES = { AF: 'Afghanistan', … }; country =  COUNTRIES[…];` at the same time? (Or `['AF' => 'Afghanistan', …]`, etc.)

Comment: I actually did in the end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My [AdvancedSorters plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4958) implements the algorithm suggested by @Halst and @SatoKatsura (joining, sorting, then unjoining) as a simple custom command:

```
:SortRangesByHeader /^case/
```

The plugin implements various other sorting methods, e.g. by folds, ranges, etc.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the link. I'm giving you the answer just because the plugin adds so much more than what I requested. Love it

Comment: Thanks! Most of its functionality arose from SO questions like yours.

Comment: It's a vimball. Never used a vimball before. How do I install this thing. I currently use pathogen and janus to install my plugins if that helps. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just `:edit AdvancedSorters-1.21.vmb.gz`, then `:so %`. Alternatively, you can use the GitHub mirror [here](https://github.com/vim-scripts/AdvancedSorters); I'm slowly moving the script development to GitHub, too.

Comment: Yeah I just used the source. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for making this plugin. After using it for a month I'm in love with it. More useful than I previously suspected

Answer (score 9):

A buzzword-compliant version of the solution suggested by @Halst:

- mark lines
- join them on a character that doesn't appear in code:

  ```
  :'<,'>s/[:;]\zs\n/@/
  ```
- mark lines again
- sort them:

  ```
  :'<,'>sort
  ```
- mark lines one last time
- split them on `@`:

  ```
  :'<,'>s/@/\r/g
  ```

You'll need to fix the last term manually.  No need for `indent`, `sort`, or any other external program.

You can also avoid marking lines if you move the relevant code to a scrap buffer and re-format it there.

Comment: Thanks sato. That's a nice little hack

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to collapse the statements into one line like this:

```
case 'AG': country = 'Antigua And Barbuda'; break;
```

By doing a visual select and replacing newline+indent with space:

```
:'<,'>s/\n  / /g
```

Then sorting the selection:

```
:'<,'>!sort
```

Then running the region of code through some pretty-printer, for example, GNU `indent`:

```
https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/indent.html
```

---

This is one advantage of adopting machine-formatted code—you can run a messy transformation (for example a regex) and then fix it all up automatically.

Comment: I like the idea of pretty printing for a cleaner result

Answer (score 3):

I created a command for this [`:SortGroup`](https://gist.github.com/PeterRincker/582ea9be24a69e6dd8e237eb877b8978)

```
" :[range]SortGroup[!] [n|f|o|b|x] /{pattern}/
" e.g. :SortGroup /^header/
" e.g. :SortGroup n /^header/
" See :h :sort for details
```

This means you can do `:SortGroup /case/`

Implementation below:

```
function! s:sort_by_header(bang, pat) range
  let pat = a:pat
  let opts = ""
  if pat =~ '^\s*[nfxbo]\s'
    let opts = matchstr(pat, '^\s*\zs[nfxbo]')
    let pat = matchstr(pat, '^\s*[nfxbo]\s*\zs.*')
  endif
  let pat = substitute(pat, '^\s*', '', '')
  let pat = substitute(pat, '\s*$', '', '')
  let sep = '/'
  if len(pat) > 0 && pat[0] == matchstr(pat, '.$') && pat[0] =~ '\W'
    let [sep, pat] = [pat[0], pat[1:-2]]
  endif
  if pat == ''
    let pat = @/
  endif

  let ranges = []
  execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . 'g' . sep . pat . sep . 'call add(ranges, line("."))'

  let converters = {
        \ 'n': {s-> str2nr(matchstr(s, '-\?\d\+.*'))},
        \ 'x': {s-> str2nr(matchstr(s, '-\?\%(0[xX]\)\?\x\+.*'), 16)},
        \ 'o': {s-> str2nr(matchstr(s, '-\?\%(0\)\?\x\+.*'), 8)},
        \ 'b': {s-> str2nr(matchstr(s, '-\?\%(0[bB]\)\?\x\+.*'), 2)},
        \ 'f': {s-> str2float(matchstr(s, '-\?\d\+.*'))},
        \ }
  let arr = []
  for i in range(len(ranges))
    let end = max([get(ranges, i+1, a:lastline+1) - 1, ranges[i]])
    let line = getline(ranges[i])
    let d = {}
    let d.key = call(get(converters, opts, {s->s}), [strpart(line, match(line, pat))])
    let d.group = getline(ranges[i], end)
    call add(arr, d)
  endfor
  call sort(arr, {a,b -> a.key == b.key ? 0 : (a.key < b.key ? -1 : 1)})
  if a:bang
    call reverse(arr)
  endif
  let lines = []
  call map(arr, 'extend(lines, v:val.group)')
  let start = max([a:firstline, get(ranges, 0, 0)])
  call setline(start, lines)
  call setpos("'[", start)
  call setpos("']", start+len(lines)-1)
endfunction
command! -range=% -bang -nargs=+ SortGroup <line1>,<line2>call <SID>sort_by_header(<bang>0, <q-args>)
```

Note: this requires Vim 8+ due to use of lambdas