# Sort/Reverse Sections in Markdown (with VIM)

Tags: sorting, text, vim, markdown, reverse

I have a Markdown file for logging. Each section has a heading named by date in chronological order. Part of the file is the following.

```
## 20200628
- Traceback
- [x] code debug
- [x] read Section 2

## 20200629
- Homepage rebuilding

## 20200630
- 13:00: Meeting Tom
```

I would like to sort the logs in a reverse way, after which it will show like the following.

```
## 20200630
- 13:00: Meeting Tom

## 20200629
- Homepage rebuilding

## 20200628
- Traceback
- [x] code debug
- [x] read Section 2
```

I was expecting to use VIM but I didn't figure out what is a proper way to achieve this. Any suggestions would be appreciated a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related post: [Is it possible to sort a groups of lines in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46660252/438329)

Answer (score 3):

We capture each block using a regex that matches its start, then
we delete it and paste at the beginning of the file.

```
:$put _ | g/^## 202006[2-3][890]/normal! dapggP
```

The `:$put _` part was used to add a blank line at the end, so each block has a blank line after it.

```
: .................... vim command mode
$ .................... at end of the file
_ .................... a blank line
|  ................... another vim command
g  ................... a global command
/  ................... start of a search
^  ................... every start of the line
##  .................. two literal ##
202006 ............... literal numbers 
[2-3]  ............... followed by 2 until 3
[890]  ............... followed by 8 9 or zero
/ .................... end of the search
normal! .............. a normal command
dap .................. delete a paragraph
gg ................... jump to the beginning of the file
P .................... put deleted text before the cursor
```