# Sort case statements in numerical order in verilog

Tags: vim, case, verilog

I have a large case statement in verilog, something like this,

> ```
>     case(stage)
>        01: begin
>            //verilog code(any number of lines)....
>        end
>        02: begin
>            //verilog code....
>        end
>        03: begin
>           //verilog code.....
>        end
>    endcase
> ```

I have shown only 3 stages here but there are 100 stages in actual. Now, sometimes I have to add/delete some stages from in between. For instance, if I have to remove stages 50-60, I have to manually update the stages from 60-100 to new values to keep the order.

I am looking for some vim commands to automate this process. I understand this is a very specific scenario so any kind of help is appreciated.
I don't want to write complicated script for it as it is trivial and I'll prefer to leave it as it is.

Comment: Well you will have to join the lines, so you can use `:sort` have a look here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8542/sort-every-few-lines

Comment: do not use hard coded numbers as case labels. Use parameters instead (could be in a separate file). Then you can have an easy script to modify or generate their values.

Comment: Related post [Is it possible to sort a groups of lines in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46660252/438329)